# How to use Gecko engine in ABCPDF v7 Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, abcpdf

We have just moved an old website to a new hosting company who has ABCPDF version 7 installed on a Windows Server 2012 VPS.

Unfortunately the existing code is not working and from my research it is due to version 7 not being compatible with later versions of IE, such as that installed on Server 2012.

So I was trying to switch to use the Gecko engine. I installed Firefox on the server. And added the code to the Classic ASP script straight after the doc object was created:

```
doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = 1
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'HtmlOptions.Engine'
```

How can I change to use the Gecko engine, and am I doing this right or is there some other issue?

As a last resort is it possible to install an older version of IE on Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably have no choice but to pay for a later version.  I've been there myself

Gecko support was introduced in v8, and it looks as if it uses its own modified version of the display engine rather than the one which comes with Firefox.  However as V8 and above support current versions of IE you probably wouldn't want to bother with Gecko.

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-13.htm

Re Internet Explorer 8 - which is the version I think you need for old versions of ABCpdf -  if your server came with IE8 installed to begin with and it's been automatically updated, then it should in theory be possible to roll back to the previous version, or even rebuild the server from scratch, and then block windows update from updating IE.  If it came with IE9 or above then you really do need to upgrade ABCpdf

Comment: Aha, didn't realise that this feature was added in v8+, and didn't realise I didn't have to install FF. I think you are right - new version of ABCPDF is the only choice.